# D3.js How to postion nodes based on indegree or outdegree using force layout?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I'm using D3.js to visualize a directed graph. I use force layout. Its behavior, in general, is very nice. However, the nodes are laid out randomly. Although, I have implemented drag event to reposition them, I want to position them from the beginning in a more systematic way.

I want to position the nodes based on their in/outdegree. For example, nodes with lower indegree are positioned in upper layer respectively to nodes with higher indegree.

My vague idea is to sort the the nodes by in/outdegree (already did), then use translate() function to manipulate the position of each node depending on the index of the nodes in the array. However, I'm stuck with the latter step. Can someone please give me some suggestion?

Here is the link to [MY CODE SNIPPET](http://pastebin.com/SfraYmed)

Layout was defined as follow:

```
var layout = d3.layout.force()                  
                      .charge(-500)
                      .linkDistance(150)
                      .size([w, h]);
```

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by "layer"? Do you want your nodes to have different parent nodes (e.g. `<g>`) depending on some property?

Comment: I mean the y-coordination.

Comment: Something like this: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1021841 ?

Comment: @Oleg: +1. That looks very helpful. I see they use e.alpha together with index i to manipulate x,y to group nodes in group. Let me see if I can make it work with mine. Basically, I want nodes with lower indegree to appear above nodes with higher indegree. x-coordinate can be random. So it should work. Thanks

Comment: Do you need the force layout for that at all if the position is determined by the degree?

Comment: @Lars I guess not necessary. But what's your suggestion for layout? I'm a newbie in D3.js

Comment: Well, you could compute the degrees, then nest by the degree value. That is, you get an array of arrays where the nodes in the inner arrays have all the same node degree. Then x position is determined by the index in the outer array and y position by the index in the inner array (or vice versa).

Comment: Why not calculating and storing the degrees in your data and using it to position the nodes using 'cx' and 'cy' attributes?